# How to list s3 bucket values into jenkins as parameter

Tags: jenkins, amazon-s3, jenkins-pipeline

I need to fetch the list of files from s3 bucket which is in different aws account to jenkins as a choice parameter which is in different aws account.

I am able to get the list over jenkins console but setting that within a choice parameter using a declarative pipeline is a challenge for me.

If anyone can help me on this.

Note: have a cross account role setup

Comment: How did you get the details here "I am able to get the list over jenkins console"?

Answer (score 0):

[Active choice plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/uno-choice/) is able to run groovy script. The script should be able to list folders in S3 and return a String Array back to the choice parameter.